# onload calling a function in controller to set value in html

Tags: angularjs

```
 $rootScope.customerName = null;

    var getCustomer = function () {
      Service.getCustomerById($scope.customerId).then(
        function (data) {
          $scope.dealers.customerName = data.customerName;
          $scope.dealers.customerNameLabel = data.customerName + ' ';
          $rootScope.customerName = ' '+ $scope.dealers.customerNameLabel;
        }
        }
      );
    };

 getCustomer();

<div>{{customerName}}</div>
```

onload I am calling a function in controller to set value in html , but it doesnt work , value is set as "abc" internally in the function whereas when i call it in html , its just undefined. Need assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually call digest cycle i.e **$Scope.$apply()**, if value is not updated.

```
$rootScope.customerName = null;
    var getCustomer = function () {
      Service.getCustomerById($scope.customerId).then(
        function (data) {
          $scope.dealers.customerName = data.customerName;
          $scope.dealers.customerNameLabel = data.customerName + ' ';
          $rootScope.customerName = ' '+ $scope.dealers.customerNameLabel;
            $Scope.$apply();
        }
        }
      );
    };

 getCustomer();

<div>{{customerName}}</div>
```

Comment: Can u post onload function too

Comment: getCustomer is my onloadfunction, the value is not setting up

Comment: hi , its working if I give $scope , then value is populating.